# Why these two functions are ambigous though their mangled names are different

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, overloading, name-mangling

Consider the following function definitions:

```
void fun(int& a)
{
    cout << "Ra" << endl;
}
```

And:

```
void fun(int a)
{
    cout << "a" << endl;
}
```

Now, when I call the function like this:

```
int a;
fun(a);
```

The call is ambiguous, because the compiler can't decide whether to call by value or by reference.

My Question is:

When I write something like this:

```
int a;
int &b = a;
fun(b);
```

It again gives ambiguity. Since b is a reference, so why not call the one where the argument is a reference.

I already saw the answers in this question: [Function Overloading Based on Value vs. Const Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465293/function-overloading-based-on-value-vs-const-reference) but it doesn't answer my question. Please Help.

Comment: BTW: Why do you use the `int&` `b` in your example? Completely superfluous.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I am using int&, to see why does the compiler allow both int and int& functions to be created. How can we call them in any way without creating ambiguity.

Comment: Read *all* the answers to the duplicate, that should be sufficient. BTW: There's also cast-to-xvalue.

Comment: The duplicate answers one part of my doubt that is how can we call the reference version. But why passing b as argument gives ambiguity here?

Comment: Because `b` is an lvalue of type `int`. And both functions are equally good matches for that. (See it not as a reference, but as simply an alias - another name - for `a`. For nearly all purposes, it is. (Exception for `decltype`.))