# Is function overloading by reference allowed when there is no ambiguity?

Tags: c++, overloading, pass-by-reference, language-lawyer

Consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int m);
void foo(int &k);

int main()
{
    foo(5); // ok, because there is no ambiguity

    int m = 5;
    //foo(m); // compile-time error, because of ambiguity
    foo(m + 0); // ok, because it's an expression of type int and not object's lvalue
}

void foo(int m)
{
    std::cout << "by value\n";
}
void foo(int &k)
{
    std::cout << "by reference\n";
}
```

I understand that it introduces ambiguity for `foo(m)`, but is this allowed, when expression is of type `int` (or another that can be converted to `int`)?

I have tried to find some standard reference on this, yet with no luck.

---

<sup>**Disclaimer**: Note that it's not duplicate of [Function Overloading Based on Value vs. Const Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465293/function-overloading-based-on-value-vs-const-reference). The `const` references are different as they can be assigned with ***rvalues***, as opposite to "ordinary", non-`const` references.</sup>

Comment: `m` is also an expression of type `int`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function Overloading Based on Value vs. Const Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465293/function-overloading-based-on-value-vs-const-reference)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes, it is allowed.**

There is no rule to prevent this overload.

> `[C++14: 13.1/1]:` Not all function declarations can be overloaded. Those that cannot be overloaded are specified here. *[..]*
>
> `[C++14: 13.1/2]:` *(blah blah lots of exceptions not including any for this case)*

It would be extremely limiting for the language to prohibit function overloads that *may* be ambiguous in certain scenarios with certain calls, and for no good reason I might add!

Answer (score 9):

13.1 [over.load] is pretty clear (apart from a multi-page note) about which functions cannot be overloaded in the same scope.

Your case is not listed there, and you can declare those overloads, you just can't necessarily use them easily. You could call the lvalue one like so:

```
void (*f)(int&) = foo;
f(m);
```

This avoids the ambiguity that happens when you call `foo(m)`.

Aside: another way to write `foo(m + 0)` is simply `foo(+m)`, the unary `+` operator converts the lvalue to an rvalue, so the `foo(int)` overload is called.