# Function overloading in C++ passing arguments by value or by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading

If we have this example functions code in C++

```
void foo(int x)  { std::cout << "foo(int)"   << std::endl; }
void foo(int& x) { std::cout << "foo(int &)" << std::endl; }
```

Is it possible to difference what function to call doing any modification in the calling arguments?

If the function foo is called in some of these ways:

```
foo( 10);

i = 10;
foo( static_cast<const int>(i));

foo( static_cast<const int&>(i));
```

it's called the first foo overloaded function, because it can't pass by reference a const argument to a non-const parameter.
But, how would you do to call the second foo overload function?
If I call the next way:

```
int i = 10;
foo( i);
```

It happens an ambiguous error because both functions are valid for this argument.

In this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/5465379/6717386 it's explained one way to resolve it: using objects instead of built-in types and doing private the copy constructor, so it can't do a copy of object value and it has to be called the second foo overload function and passing the object by reference. But, is there any way with the built-in types? I have to change the name of function to avoid the overloading?

Comment: Did you try `foo( static_cast<int&>(i));`?

Comment: You could use `void foo(int x)` and `void foo(int *x)` instead.

Comment: @mvidelgauz Yes, I have tried it. Same error than above. :(

Comment: @DimChtz Yes, that way works. But using references?

Comment: The easiest solution would be to write better functions. Or put them in different namespaces.

Comment: @nvoigt Thanks, you're right. That's a solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may do a cast (of the function) to select the overload function:

```
static_cast<void (&)(int&)>(foo)(i);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/JoTqa3)

Comment: Thanks, it works fine!. But, I'm trying your solution with classes and methods and it appears the error _error: invalid static_cast from type '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to type 'void (&)(Punto&)'_. It's [here link:](http://ideone.com/ZxrqOt)

Comment: @CarlosUrda You need to include the class name in the method pointer, e.g. static_cast<void (MyClass::*)(int&)>(&MyClass::foo);

Comment: @CarlosUrda: Syntax is even uglier, see [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e83fc0f4e3e76603).

Comment: @CarlosUrda: `const` is missing in the cast for the method : [Demo](http://ideone.com/LFGS1W)

Answer (score 4):

In most instance, function overloading involves distinct parameter types and different input parameter lengths.

Your attempt is generally a bad practice and the resulting compiled code is compiler dependent and code optimization may even worsen things even more.

You may consider **simply** adding a second parameter to the second method, something like this:

```
void foo(int x)  { std::cout << "foo(int)"   << std::endl; }
void foo(int& x, ...) { std::cout << "foo(int &, ...)" << std::endl; }
```

where `...` could be a boolean type, say: `bool anotherFunction`

So calling `foo(param1, param2)` would simply call the second code and everybody is fine.

Comment: Compiler dependent ? Unless your compiler is broken, this has no reason to change behaviour whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't like your solution. I'm trying use the same function name for setter a getters in a class.

`class Circulo 
{
 public:
  void centro( const Punto&);  // setter
  void centro( Punto&) const;  // getter
 
 private:
  Punto centro_;
};`

Comment: Sorry, but the question wasn't explicit  enough. I just think keeping simple things simple is the key. 

However, about the getter and setter, for a more readable code, you can consider NOT using parameters for your getters. You would've still prevented this error if you follow this approach and your code would still be very clean.

Comment: -Jarod42 had a point, but do you have to static('ally) cast your getter / setter to use them? lets keep it simple please.

@Quentin ever wondered why your c++ compiler converts your old Uniform initializers into functions?

See this: https://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/
Skip to Uniform initializers.

Comment: @CarlosUrda: then simply do `class Circle { const Point& Center(); const;Point& Center(); /* ... */};

Comment: @Gamma.X most vexing parse...? I don't really get your point. Maybe I simply misunderstood your phrase, but if some code's behaviour depends on the compiler, or even on the optimizer, then it is at least implementation-defined (and undefined at worst). There is no such thing in this question.

Comment: @Jarod42 You're absolutely right. Getter method exists mainly for getting the value, not for setting in a variable the value to get. ¡Mil gracias!

Comment: @CarlosUrda - My point is that both functions are syntactically identical when you consider supplying a NULL in the function. Hence, the ambiguity. 
However, like I said, if you've NOT attempted using a parameter for your getter method. We probably could be discussing something else right now :)

Answer (score 4):

Very strange design, but if you want... I'll offer a solution as strange as your design Use *Xreference* in function signature. Then in the function you can check what you need to do using `std::is_lvalue_reference`, `std::is_rvalue_reference`.
Something like this

```
template<class T>
void foo(T&& x)
{
  static_assert(std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, int>::value, "!"); 
  if (std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value)
    std::cout << "do here what you want in foo(int x)";
  else
    std::cout << "do here what you want in foo(int & x)";
}

int main()
{
  int x = 5;
  foo(x); //"do here what you want in foo(int x)" - will be printed
  foo(std::move(x)); //"do here what you want in foo(int & x)" - will be printed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Despite the good answer of @Jarod42, as an alternative solution you can rely on a templated entry point and the overloading of an internal function (if you don't want to deal with explicit casts, of course).
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>

void foo_i(char, int x)  { std::cout << "foo(int)"   << std::endl; }
void foo_i(int, int &x) { std::cout << "foo(int &)" << std::endl; }

template<typename T>
void foo(T &&t) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, int>::value, "!");
    foo_i(0, std::forward<T>(t));
}

int main() {
    foo( 10);
    int i = 10;
    foo( static_cast<const int>(i));
    foo( static_cast<const int &>(i)); 
    foo(i);
}
```

The `static_assert` serves the purpose of checking the parameter to be something that involves `int` (that is `int`, `int &`, `const int &`, int &&`, and so on).

As you can see from the code above, `foo(i)` will print:

> foo(int &)

As expected.

Answer (score 1):

Another one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void foo(int x)
{
    std::cout << "foo(int)\n";
}

template<typename T>
void foo(T&& x)
{
    std::cout << "foo(int&)\n";
}

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    foo(i);           // foo(int)
    foo(std::ref(i)); // foo(int&)
}
```

Comment: bad solution. In general it is a bad idea to overload functions the only argument of which is Xreference. For example: const int i = 10; foo(i); will print "foo(int&)\n"

Comment: @AndreyNekrasov Well, another bad solution, perhaps, but  `const int i = 10; foo(i);` prints foo(int) in my gcc.

Answer (score -1):

I just happened to have stumbled upon this post and was surprised not to find the typical SFINAE solution. So, there you go:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T,
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_lvalue_reference<T>{}, int>::type = 0>
void foo(T)
{ std::cout << "foo(int)"   << std::endl; }

template<typename T,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_lvalue_reference<T>{}, int>::type = 0>
void foo(T&)
{ std::cout << "foo(int &)" << std::endl; }
 
int main() {
    int i = 42;
    int& r = i;
    foo<decltype(i)>(i);
    foo<decltype(r)>(r);
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/Mdf7K1qv7)

Comment: The only way to call this is `foo<decltype(r)>` since `T` is not used in the implementation; why do you feel SFINAE is appropriate in this case? Your solution is not an _overload_ since it requires explicit instantiation to name the function

Comment: @Human-Compiler I was just wondering if constraining the functions could make this work somehow. But you're right, there is no overload resolution taking place here, so I guess the SFINAE reference is misplaced. We could still induce overload resolution of function templates by constraining both functions, which would look a bit nicer with C++20.

Comment: @Human-Compiler Could you reconsider your comment, since your it no longer applies anymore?